# How to detect duplicate entries in a boost::property_tree

Tags: c++, boost-propertytree

I'd like to recursively traverse a boost::property_tree with the specific aim of finding and culling duplicate entries.  Is there a way, once an path in the tree has been discovered, to issue a get() on the parent tree which excludes some instance of the path specified?  I'm concerned that solving this problem may require another recursive traversal for each element (beginning from the current branch) to positively identify duplicate entries.

Comment: One way to approach this may be to to copy the tree.  Iterate the source tree and put item into the new tree by path,  This may overwrite the original entries with the subsequent duplicate entries, which is what I want.

Comment: This approach seems to be working...May post solution as answer.